# Detect 10V...To.. 260V AC/DC with HCPL-3700

Tags: ac, dc, opto-isolator

I want to detect voltage between 10V and 260V AC / DC, I have thought to use the HCPL-3700 but if I put the 47k resistors the output is activated, but if I apply 12V the output is not activated.

[image: schematic]

Does anyone know if it can be done with this chip, or does this one not work and I have to use another type?

Basically I want to activate a 5Vdc PIC with whatever voltage is applied. I don't need zero crossings or anything special, only that it be activated with that input voltage range.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Edit] in the datasheet link to make it easy for your readers and so that we're all reading the same one.

Comment: Please remove (CLOSED) from the title of your question. It's confusing and not how this site works. You can accept @csabahu's answer. This will mark your question as answered on this site and give csabahu credit for it.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the same resistors. The input does not detect voltage but current. To switch on, approx. [2.4 mA](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/HCPL3700-D.pdf) current required.
[image: nulla]

So in its current state (2x47k) it will turn on around 240V.
[image: egy]

[image: kettő]

This is just enough to detect 230VAC, but not for lower voltage.

For 10 V, the maximum external resistance would be 2k.
[image: 10v1]

[image: 10v2]

So it can be used in a narrow voltage range. On the data sheet, this figure shows the voltage at which it switches on and off with a given resistor.
At 94k (2x47) these values ​​are approx. 240V and 120V.
[image: öt]

So it can be used very well to indicate e.g. the presence of 230V, but is not suitable for signaling a wide voltage range (10V ... 230V).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to detect a voltage of 10V to 350V with at least 2 mA for the HCPL-3700 (simulated with D2). R1 can be decreased to get higher current if needed. I used an LED (D1) for the voltage reference that establishes the current, but two diodes could be used as well. The maximum power dissipation in Q1 is about 2.1 W, or even less, as I used the current in D2 times the full 350 V applied. I don't know if the BC847C is rated for 350 V. That important parameter is missing in CircuitLab. An MJE340 is rated for 300V and 20W. Changing R2 to 180k and R1 to 180 ohms, the circuit provides 2.3 mA at 10 V and 8 mA at 350 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUJh6N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: LED currents]

Note that the simulation spans 0-350 ms, which corresponds to 0-350 V applied, so it also functions as a voltage sweep.

LED current plot for updated circuit:

[image: LED currents]

Comment: Paul nice design, as I understand your circuit it is a constant current source. I It is a good design except for one small problem the OP will have.The BC847C is rated at 45 V, 100 mA and used as an NPN general-purpose transistor per the Nexperia data sheet. The PMBTA44 400 V, 0.3 A NPN high-voltage low VCEsat transistor might be a good alternate. There are many other possibilities in this and other packages. Note the SOT23 will not dissipate the amount of power required.